# Elasticsearch replicate SELECT id, COUNT(id) FROM sometable

Tags: elasticsearch

In ElasticSearch using `aggs` you can easily replicate this sql query

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table;
```

But I want this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), id FROM table;
```

Or even better I want to do:

```
SELECT COUNT(price) * price FROM table;
```

Is this even possible in Elasticsearch?

I have tried “terms” and similar , using pipelines or `bucket_script`  BUT the problem is `doc_count` is not accessible in `buckets_path` .

Comment: `doc_count` can be accessed in `buckets_path` using `_count`: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#_special_paths

Comment: Thanks@Val you are correct, but still I have not been able to make it work as a query, still fetching all the docs in Python to do the calculation locally,

Comment: Please show the query you're sending

Comment: Thanks @Val I don’t have a query. How would you go about it. I mean this is an elementary question from someone who is new to elasticsearch

Comment: You said you have "tried terms and similar, using pipelines or bucket_script"... That's why I'm asking to see what you've tried so far.